# Default uncaught exception handler in Spark driver process

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jvm

I wrote a spark libary in Scala where I would like to do some action before an uncaught exception happens on the driver process (log it, increment an error metric, ...). I tried multiple times to use `setUncaughtExceptionHandler` in the current Thread but this doesn't work.

```
Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler {
  override def uncaughtException(t: Thread, th: Throwable): Unit = {
    // do something
}
```

If I spawn another thread it works fine. Any idea of what can I do to achieve my goal?

I see that Spark has a default `Exception handler`, which maybe cannot be overwritten? https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler.scala

Comment: Hi @alex it is possible to post some code with your scenario? My question is how do you use uncaughtException and which thread you pass as param

Comment: updated the question. I want to add some logging stamements mainly

Comment: Can you find out what instance `Thread.currentThread()` is? You can retrieve that with `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`

Comment: My thought is to check if `setUncaughtExceptionHandler` is set again after the invocation of your code.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If I print `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` I get the stack trace of the current method executed (the method which would generate the exception for example)

Comment: Facing same problem here. Any solutions?